# "Set-PSDebug -Trace 2" causes a variable assignment to fail

Tags: powershell

This two-line PS script fails if debug tracing is set to level 2:

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
$Process = Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList localhost -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait
```

It fails with this error:

```
Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Process = Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList localhost -NoNe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromAnyTypeToString
```

If I set -Trace 1 or no tracing, it works. If I don't try to assign $Process in -Trace 2, it works.

I wouldn't expect Set-PSDebug to modify the execution environment, but that seems to be the case here. Is this expected behavior? Or perhaps a bug in PowerShell?

Version information:

```
PS C:\Users\Eric> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: I cannot repro this. These commands work successfully on my machine, using the same version.  Check if your script contains unexpected things, like invisible characters, or if perhaps the encoding is incorrect. Retype it if necessary. If that's not it, check if your session auto-loads any modules that might be interfering.

Comment: If I copy and paste exactly what I have posted here, I get the error. Is that what you did @JeroenMostert?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that, into a new PowerShell 5.1 window from the command line and also as a script file that's invoked. It fails, however, when executed from the ISE -- is that perhaps what you're doing? The ISE is rather notorious for not behaving as the shell would.

Comment: FWIW, I **can** repro here - exactly the same $PSVersionTable versions as the OP, on Windows 10 v21H2 (19044.2486), *and* PSVersion 5.1.22621.963 on Windows 11 22H2 build 22621.1105 - start a Windows PowerShell session in the "new" Terminal and paste the code in, run and get the error...

Comment: Just playing around - ```[string](Start-Process -FilePath ping -ArgumentList localhost -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait)``` gives the same error , so maybe ```Set-PSDebug``` is also trying to cast to string for some reason. before the assignment..

Comment: Wait, never mind, I can repro it from the command line now too. Either I did something else before (but I have no idea what) or I just overlooked it somehow.